# Password verifier code , deals with C++ cstrings

Tags: c++, string

So this code is supposed to verify a password inputted by the user. The password must be atleast 6 characters, it should have atleast one uppercase and atleast one lowercase character, and there should be atleast one digit in it. I tried to do it this way, when i run it, it asks me for the password, but then it doesn't show anything if i enter an invalid password.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{
    const int size = 1000;

char password[size];

int count;

int times1 = 0;

int times2 = 0;

int times3 = 0;
cout << "Please enter your password: ";
cin.getline(password,size);


if (strlen(password) < 6){

    "Not valid, your password should be atleast 6 letters";

}

for(count = 0; count < strlen(password); count++){

    if (isupper(password[count])) {

        times1++;

    }

    if (islower(password[count])){

        times2++;

    }

    if (isdigit(password[count])){

        times3++;

    }

}

if (times1 == 0) {

    "Invalid, the password should contain atleast one uppercase letter";

}

if (times2 == 0) {

    "Invalid, the password should contain atleast one lowercase letter";

}

if (times3 == 0) {

    "Invalid, the password should contain atleast one digit";

}



cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because you forgot to print anything when the password is wrong:

```
"Not valid, your password should be atleast 6 letters";
```

should be

```
cout << "Not valid, your password should be atleast 6 letters";
```

Comment: @user566094, yup, it happens. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you just have to use std::cout << ""Invalid, the password should contain atleast one digit" << std::endl to output the message you want.